# Ex of Acronym, not Initialism, no vowels in form

Tags: phonology, acronyms

I am wondering if there are any good examples of **acronyms** that are *not*  **initialisms** which contain no vowels.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarify what you mean by acronym vs initialism? Off the top of my head, a lot of computing standards would qualify: JPG, PNG…

Comment: Acronyms & initialisms are both shortened words/phrases (usually nouns/pronouns), but while an initialism has the sound segments pronounced individually (e.g. FBI, NSA), an acronym is the sound segments pronounced as a word or complete meaning segment (e.g. NASA, NATO). JPG might work for my purposes. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trivia, not linguistics.

Comment: Excuse me @curiousdannil, contrary to popular belief, your brain chooses to insert vowel segments between obstruents, and phonologists know that these sounds are not randomly chosen. This is not a trivia question, rather, a linguistics one. Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two examples.  One is BP or BPS, which stands for "basis point" or "basis points", used in reference to rate changes in a financial instrument or the difference between two interest rates.  They are pronounced, respectively, "bip" and "bips".

The other example is "Tcl", for "Tool Command Language", a scripting language commonly used for rapid prototyping, scripted applications, GUIs, and testing.  It is pronounced "tickle" by most users.

I think these examples meet your criteria.